# display parent and children categories in a channel entry

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I can't seem to find a way to display the parent and then the child category in a entry:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="6" }
<a href="{site_url}Products/detail/{categories}{category_url_title}/{url_title}">Details &raquo;</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

this needs to display a link to domain.com/Products/detail/Parent-Category/Child-Category/url-title

I can only seem to get the parent to display

I also tried GW Categories with no luck:

```
<a href="{path="Products/detail/{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear" backspace="1" depth="1|2"}{cat_url_title}/{/exp:gwcode_categories}{url_title}"}">Details &raquo;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
<a href="{site_url}Products/detail/{exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear" backspace="1" depth="1|2"}{cat_url_title}/{/exp:gwcode_categories}/{url_title}">Details &raquo;</a>
```